# Exclude one specific path with OkHttp CertificatePinner

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I have SSL pinning in my project implemented with `OkHttp` `CertificatePinner`, but wanna exclude one specific path. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create another OkHttpClient instance that doesn't have the pinner. Use OkHttpClient.newBuilder() to build a client that shares everything with another one.